# How can I stop SQL Server Management Studio replacing 'SELECT *' with the column list?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SQL Server Mgmt Studio is driving me crazy.

If I create a view and SELECT '*' from a table, it's all OK and I can save the view.
Looking at the SQL for the view (eg.by scripting a CREATE) reveals that the 'SELECT *' really is saved to the view's SQL.

But as soon as I reopen the view using the GUI (right click > modify), SELECT * is replaced with a column list of all the columns in the table.

How can I stop Management Studio from doing this ? I want my 'SELECT *' to remain just that.

Perhaps it's just the difficulty of googling 'SELECT *' that prevented me from finding anything remotely relevant to this (i did put it in double quotes).

Please, I am highly experienced in Transact-SQL, so please DON'T give me a lecture on why I shouldn't be using SELECT *.  I know all the pros and cons and I do use it at times.  It's a language feature, and like all language features can be used for good or evil (I emphatically do NOT agree that it is never appropriate to use it).

Edit: I'm giving Marc the answer, since it seems it is not possible to turn this behaviour off. Problem is considered closed. I note that Enterprise Manager did no similar thing.
The workaround is to either edit SQL as text, or go to a product other than Managment Studio. Or constantly edit out the column list and replace the * every time you edit a view.  Sigh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SQL Server Mgmt Studio creates a view, I assume they're expanding the * to the complete list of columns that are present in the underlying table(s) at that particular time exactly for this reason: what if one of the underlying tables changes? Do you want the new columns to just simply show up in every view that references that table?? Seriously???

I think Microsoft tries to impmenent the "element of least surprise" here - your view will contain those columns that are present at the time the view gets created - and it stays that way, unless you explicitly and knowingly change that.

I for one wouldn't want to have my views suddenly having more columns than before, when an underlying table changes..... do you??

And I don't think there's any setting in Mgmt Studio to turn this behavior off, sorry.

Comment: +1: Sums up my opinion as well. The described behavior is, for once, a feature.

Comment: 1. He explicitly asked to not get any lectures about Select *. 2. You can avoid the auto-expansion by picking "Script View As" instead of "Design" from the right-click menu. 3. It is acceptable to use "Create View dbo.TableName AS Select * From OtherDatabase.dbo.TableName" when you need to link two databases together.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: ok, thanks for your viewpoint. I don't agree, but that's ok.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I think the consensus so far is 'no'. 
<rant> 
Yes, I DO want new columns to simply show up in my view. That's exactly what I want. I DO realise that the presence of new columns will 'break' my view, until I do an sp_refreshview to regenerate the metadata. If I MEANT 'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ... , ColN', I'd type it, or use one of the many methods of autogenerating the list. What I MEAN is 'SELECT *', but it seems M$ have decided I'm not allowed to use this valuable language feature any more. It's like SQL-McCarthyism. </rant>

Comment: Sorry if I get emotional, but SQL Enterprise Manager was a good tool and I'm very fond of it. MSSMS lacks sooo many of its good features, is slow and very prescriptive. Unfortunately EM does not play with SQL2005+, so I'm being dragged kicking and screaming to using this 'management tool'. It quite significantly affects my productivity. I don't have any issues with text-editing SQL in the new tool, but that's a no-brainer.  Sometimes the GUI is way quicker and that's what I asking about here.

Comment: @Ben: well, I for one do **not** long to go back to the days of EM/QA - having two tools, always having to go back and forth between them, is no fun. I much prefer SSMS despite it being "speed challenged" - but things like Intellisense (in 2008) and other goodies make up for that many times over!

Comment: @marc: hmmm, I've always thought the new tool has a Frankenstein-like quality about it, in that it tries to do too many things.  I'd prefer two tools that work quickly and well.  The intellisense will be good (if I ever make it to 2008 :-) but issues like the cause of this question are just plain boneheaded.  I find it really hard to suppress the instinct to flee in horror from this product.

Comment: @Ben McIntyre: maybe I can interest you in "MiniSQL" ? http://www.pksoftware.net/MiniSqlQuery/

Comment: @marc: thanks for the link ! I'll certainly look into it. I've always liked the graphical view, especially when I am dealing with cascades of 10 or more tables, and its one-click column selection. But I suppose a good SQL intellisense enabled tool might cut it. I note Redgate also have a swathe of excellent SQL products. I investigated all the products about 5 years ago and 'Toad for SQL Server' looked like the best EM/QA alternative at the time; I installed it but never got around to actually firing up and using it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the GUI editor.

Instead use the T-SQL editor. You get this by selecting "Script View As" -> "ALTER to" -> "New Query Window" from the right-click menu.

Comment: Thanks; with respect I can edit the SQL raw, but that's not what I'm talking about here.  There are some times it's best to do that, and sometimes the GUI is way quicker.

Comment: Sorry, but unless I missed somethings that's the closest you are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these: they are alternatives to using the GUI and can be setup as snippets with keyboard shortcuts:

```
select view_definition 
from information_schema.views
where table_name = 'viewname'
```

or

```
exec sp_helptext 'viewname'
```

The results will retain the "select *". (Tested)